# Part of proof that supremum norm is (positive) definite. $||f||_\infty =0 \implies f=0$.

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, supremum-and-infimum

I want to prove that for a bounded function $f$, we have:

> $$ ||f||_\infty =0 \implies f=0. $$

Simply observe that if we denote the domain of definition by $D$:
$$ ||f||_\infty = \sup_{x \in D}|f(x)|$$
We know that the supremum is the least upper bound, so for any $y \in D $:
$$ |f(y)| \leq \sup_{x \in D} |f(x)|=0$$
But we also know that the Euclidean metric is positive definite, so
$|f(y) |\geq 0$,  and we get that for all $y \in D$ we have $|f(y)|=0$, but now again by positive definiteness:

$$|f(y)|=0 \iff f(y)=0.$$

Is my reasoning correct?

Comment: It's correct, but for a proof this simple I would want to see the dummy variable that is being dropped from the argument: If $\Vert f\Vert_{\infty}=0$ then $0=\Vert f\Vert_{\infty}=\sup_{x}|f(x)|\geq|f(y)|$ for any $y$.

Comment: This is Quite OK.

Comment: Is this what you meant? I think that's a useful addition parsiad.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is correct, alternatively, as suggested by Quiliup, We can immediately conclude that since  for all $y \in D$ $$|f(y)|\leq 0$$
By positive definiteness of the Euclidean norm it must hold that for all $y \in D$ we have $|f(y)|=0$ and hence $f(y)=0$.